# equivalent of metric spaces and their topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

how we can give an example of two metrics on a space that induce the same topology , but are not equivalent!(so do we can generalize our definition about equivalent of metrics?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with $d$ unbounded and consider the metric $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$. This induces the same topology, but is not equivalent to $d$, since it is bounded

Comment: short and sweet!